# How to implicitly start Clojure REPL with JVM_OPTS env variable in Windows?

Tags: windows, clojure, read-eval-print-loop

I am on Windows 10 and  trying next

- set JVM_OPTS to `"-Dclojure.server.repl={:port 4555 :accept clojure.core.server/repl :server-daemon false}"` - then `lein repl` *do not start* any **Socket** REPL (only its own nREPL)
- set JVM_OPTS to `-Dclojure.server.repl="{:port,50505,:accept,clojure.core.server/repl}"` - then `lein repl` throws error `4555 was unexpected at this time.`
- set JVM_OPTS to `-Dclojure.server.repl={:port 4555 :accept clojure.core.server/repl :server-daemon false}` - then `lein repl` *do not start* any **Socket** REPL
- and only when I try this from PowerShell `java -"Dclojure.server.mine={:port 4555,:accept,clojure.core.server/repl}" -jar Path/to/clojure-1.8.0.jar` then I got an Socket REPL on `telnet localhost 4555`

But I want it from Environment variable due to I want to start it from Java app deployed on Wildfly when I need it.

**UPDATE**

Well, finally I managed to start Socket REPL like this 
`java -jar C:\Share\clojure-1.8.0.jar` with **_JAVA_OPTIONS** env defined as `-Dclojure.server.repl="{:port 4555 :accept clojure.core.server/repl :server-daemon false}"`. But **JVM_OPTS** is still useless in this case. And `lein repl` gave me `4555 was unexpected at this time.` again.

Comment: I think you mixed up the error messages from your second and third scenario. How are you setting JVM_OPTS? I'd look into whether your JVM_OPTS settings is actually getting to lein at all.

Comment: Well, I am setting it in PS as `$env:JVM_OPTS = '-Dclojure.server.repl="{:port 4555 :accept clojure.core.server/repl :se
rver-daemon false}"'`